# Extract intervals from list with same values C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, datetime

I have the following class :

```
class TimeInterval
    DateTime Start 
    DateTime Finish
    int Value
```

I have a list, which has TimeIntervals in it with a following "Value" variable : 
0 0 1 2 1 1 3 3 3 3 1

Basically I would like to get the days where the value is 0 one after another in a TimeInterval object, get the days, where it is 1 (the single instance and where it is 1 sequentially), get where it is 2 and so on.

I would like to know if there is any neat way of getting intervals, where the values are the same.

Example data : 
the list would consist of the following objects : 
TimeInterval1 (2/2/2015, 2/3/2015, 1) (StartDate, FinishDate, Value)
TimeInterval2 (2/3/2015, 2/4/2015, 1)
TimeInterval3 (2/4/2015, 2/5/2015, 2)
TimeInterval4 (2/5/2015, 2/6/2015, 2)
TimeInterval5 (2/6/2015, 2/7/2015, 2)
TimeInterval6 (2/7/2015, 2/7/2015, 1)

This for example would gave me the following intervals : 
2/2/2015 - 2/4/2015 with Value 1
2/4/2015 - 2/7/2015 with Value 2
2/7/2015 - 2/7/2015 with Value 1

I have the following code, but this is not working correctly for the last item...

```
public static List<TimeInterval> FindRanges(List<TimeInterval> rp)
    {
        List<TimeInterval> timeintervals = new List<TimeInterval>();
        Boolean stop = false;
        DateTime IntervalStart=DateTime.Now;
        DateTime IntervalFinish=DateTime.Now;
        dynamic Value=0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= rp.Count-1; i++)
        {
            if(stop==false)
            {
                IntervalStart = rp[i].StartDate;
                IntervalFinish = rp[i].StartDate; //we might need to put in the startdate here aswell
                Value = rp[i].Value;
                stop=true;
            }
                if (Convert.ToDouble("0" + rp[i].Value) == Convert.ToDouble("0" + rp[i + 1].Value))
                {
                    Value = rp[i].Value;
                    IntervalFinish = rp[i + 1].StartDate; //we might need to put in the startdate here aswell
                }
                else //we found an interval so we construct one
                {
                    stop = false;
                    if (Convert.ToDouble("0" + Value) != 0)
                    {
                        TimeInterval t = new TimeInterval(IntervalStart, IntervalFinish, Value, i);
                        timeintervals.Add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return timeintervals;
    }
```

Comment: Add some example data and the desired output to see clearer what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: "IntervalFinish = rp[i + 1].StartDate;" will fail with "for (int i = 0; i <= rp.Count-1; i++)" for sure

Comment: Got it Florian! Added a small example

Comment: any reason why you are using the dynamic keyword? There is no need to do so at all.

Comment: Whats the 4th parameter in the constructor?

Comment: I'm using the dynamic keyword, because I'm getting data from MSP, and that data can be either a double, or an empty string.

About the 4th parameter : I'm reusing the TimeInterval class from somewhere else in the code... at this instance, the Index is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testData = new List<TimeInterval>
                       {
                           new TimeInterval(new DateTime(2015, 02, 02), new DateTime(2015, 03, 02), 1),
                           new TimeInterval(new DateTime(2015, 03, 02), new DateTime(2015, 04, 02), 1),
                           new TimeInterval(new DateTime(2015, 04, 02), new DateTime(2015, 05, 02), 2),
                           new TimeInterval(new DateTime(2015, 05, 02), new DateTime(2015, 06, 02), 2),
                           new TimeInterval(new DateTime(2015, 06, 02), new DateTime(2015, 07, 02), 2),
                           new TimeInterval(new DateTime(2015, 07, 02), new DateTime(2015, 07, 02), 1),
                       };
        var result = FindRanges(testData);

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start: {0} End: {1} Value: {2}",item.StartDate,item.FinishDate,item.Value);
        }

    }

    public static List<TimeInterval> FindRanges(List<TimeInterval> rp)
    {
        List<TimeInterval> timeintervals = new List<TimeInterval>();
        Boolean stop = false;
        DateTime intervalStart = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime intervalFinish = DateTime.Now;
        dynamic value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= rp.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!stop)
            {
                intervalStart = rp[i].StartDate;
                intervalFinish = rp[i].FinishDate; //we might need to put in the startdate here aswell
                value = rp[i].Value;
                stop = true;
            }
            if (i < rp.Count - 1  && Convert.ToDouble("0" + rp[i].Value) == Convert.ToDouble("0" + rp[i + 1].Value))
            {
                //value = rp[i].Value;
                intervalFinish = rp[i+1].FinishDate; //we might need to put in the startdate here aswell
            }
            else //we found an interval so we construct one
            {
                stop = false;
                if (Convert.ToDouble("0" + value) != 0)
                {
                    TimeInterval t = new TimeInterval(intervalStart, intervalFinish, value);
                    timeintervals.Add(t);
                }
            }
        }
        return timeintervals;
    }
}

internal class TimeInterval
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime FinishDate { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public TimeInterval(DateTime startIn, DateTime finishIn, int valueIn)
    {
        StartDate = startIn;
        FinishDate = finishIn;
        Value = valueIn;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works and produces your given output but the question is if it is the right answer for all cases

Comment: Edited ... using finish date now it produces your intervals